# convert mm/dd/yyyy to m/d/yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to convert 05/01/2017 to 5/1/2017 by using the format custom text field on excel but the date won't change.

I have a whole set of dates in Column A but will need to transform it as it is in Colum B, however, the formating the fields won't work

```
     A            B (Result)
10/15/2017      10/15/2017
05/01/2017      5/1/2017
05/15/2017      5/15/2017
```

Comment: It means the dates are actually text that look like dates.

Comment: The format "m" produces almost the same results as the format "mm" in excel.  Notice the leading zeros are gone from 05.  But it wouldn't convert 10 to 0 obviously.  What were you expecting to see?  If you want two digits for the day, use "dd".

Answer (score 2):

In **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2))
```

and copy down.  Then format column **B** as you wish.

[image]

***Note:***

This is a reasonable approach if the data in column **A** is *Text*.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom date format in Excel

If none of the predefined Excel date formats is suitable for you, you are free to create your own.

In an Excel sheet, select the cells you want to format.
Press Ctrl+1 to open the Format Cells dialog.

On the Number tab, select Custom from the Category list and type the date format you want in the Type box.

The easiest way to set a custom date format in Excel is to start from an existing format close to what you want. To do this, click Date in the Category list first, and select one of existing formats under Type. After that click Custom and make changes to the format displayed in the Type box.

When setting up a custom date format in Excel, you can use the following codes.

Code

```
Description

Example (January 1, 2005)
m
Month number without a leading zero
1
mm
Month number with a leading zero
01
mmm
Month name, short form
Jan
mmmm
Month name, full form
January
mmmmm
Month as the first letter
J (stands for January, June and July)
d
Day number without a leading zero
1
dd
Day number with a leading zero
01
ddd
Day of the week, short form
Mon
dddd
Day of the week, full form
Monday
yy
Year (last 2 digits)
05
yyyy
Year (4 digits)
2005
When setting up a custom time format in Excel, you can use the following codes.
Code
Description
Displays as
h
Hours without a leading zero
0-23
hh
Hours with a leading zero
00-23
m
Minutes without a leading zero
0-59
mm
Minutes with a leading zero
00-59
s
Seconds without a leading zero
0-59
ss
Seconds with a leading zero
00-59
AM/PM
Periods of the day
(if omitted, 24-hour time format is used)
AM or PM
Note. If you're setting up a custom format that includes date and time values and you use "m" immediately after "hh" or "h" or immediately before "ss" or "s", Microsoft Excel will display minutes instead of the month.
When creating a custom date format in Excel, you can use a comma (,) dash (-), slash (/), colon (:) and other characters.
For example, the same date and time, say January 13, 2015 13:03, can be displayed in a various ways:
Format
Displays as
dd-mmm-yy
13-Jan-15
mm/dd/yyyy
01/13/2015
m/dd/yy
1/13/15
dddd, m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM
Tuesday, 1/13/15 1:03 PM
ddd, mmmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss
Tue, January 13, 2015 13:03:00
```

Web link:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/